# Display real time preview on chrome using postman

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, postman

[image]

I am creating an alternate login method. Where I am sending an `Email(test@gmail.com)` and a `SessionKey(asdasd@3)` both of type string.

To a rest API with (POST). The preview shows on POSTMAN that it is working and the user is logged in, but the application is running on chrome on a port does not get logged in.

The user should get logged in and the next page should be displayed on the google chrome browser. After the values are sent using POSTMAN

I want to see the preview on google chrome rather than on POSTMAN preview.

Comment: For server side, try to use:
`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(log data here)`
For Front-End side:
`console.log(log data here)`

Comment: I am sorry, maybe i was not clear. I want to see the preview on google chrome. When i send those values to the REST API the next page should be seen on google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It's because CORS problem. When you execute a call to REST API over Postman, the CORS validation won't be set. When you execute a call to REST API over the browser, the API will validate the original domain sent by browser against the allowed ones in REST API.

To allow your domain can be accepted by the API you can enable it like following

```
[EnableCors("http://localhost:4200,http://something.rooturl.com", "*", "*")]
public class YourController : ApiController
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I would like to know if there is a way to see the result displayed on google chrome rather than on the preview of POSTMAN".

Yes, you can see it on google developers tools. Right click on chrome page and select `Inspect Element`. Then `Networks Tab`

[image: Google chrome dev tools for checking api request and responses]

However, it is recommended to use Postman for testing apis. If you are getting response in postman means that the API is working fine. The problem is in your implementation. Can you post some code that you have written in ASP.NET?